# Searchbar in viewcontroller (uitableview)

Tags: xcode4.5

I try to create a simple app for iPhone.

In it i have a tableview and a detailview of the tableview, and last a searchbar to filter the tableview.

The tableview and detailview works fine, but the searchhbar dos not work as it should.

When i type in a search word it displays the whole tableview and the detailview dos not work 
search mode.

When i cancel the search mode the detail view works again.

So obviusly my filter code is wrong, and i haven't got my detailview inside my filter code but i don't now how to do that correctly.

Hope someone can help me, my code look like this:

my *.h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class DetailViewController;

@interface MasterViewController : UITableViewController <UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchDisplayDelegate>

{
    NSArray *originalData;
    NSMutableArray *searchData;

    UISearchBar *searchBar;
    UISearchDisplayController *searchDisplayController;

}

@property (strong, nonatomic) DetailViewController *detailViewController;

@end
```

my *.m file:

```
#import "MasterViewController.h"

#import "DetailViewController.h"

@interface MasterViewController () {
    NSMutableArray *_objects;
}
@end

@implementation MasterViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        self.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Opslag", @"Opslag");
        _objects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        //title
        //detail

        NSDictionary * obj1 = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"this_title", @"title", @"this_detail", @"detail", nil];
        NSDictionary * obj2 = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"some_title2", @"title", @"some_detail2", @"detail", nil];
        NSDictionary * obj3 = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"some_title3", @"title", @"some_detail3", @"detail", nil];
        NSDictionary * obj4 = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"some_title4", @"title", @"some_detail4", @"detail", nil];

        [_objects addObject:obj1];
        [_objects addObject:obj2];
        [_objects addObject:obj3];
        [_objects addObject:obj4];

        originalData = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:obj1, obj2, obj3, nil];
        searchData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 160, 44)];
    searchDisplayController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:searchBar contentsController:self];

    searchDisplayController.delegate = self;
    searchDisplayController.searchResultsDataSource = self;

    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar;

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



#pragma mark - Table View

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return _objects.count;
}

// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [[_objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"title"];

    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[_objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"detail"];




    return cell;
}

#pragma mark - searchDisplayControllerDelegate

- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
    [searchData removeAllObjects];

    NSArray *group;

    for(group in originalData)
    {
        NSMutableArray *newGroup = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        NSString *element;

        for(element in group)
        {
            NSRange range = [element rangeOfString:searchString options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

            if (range.length > 0) {
                [newGroup addObject:element];
            }
        }

        if ([newGroup count] > 0) {
            [searchData addObject:newGroup];
        }


    }

    return YES;
}


- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (!self.detailViewController) {
        self.detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];
    }
    NSDictionary *object = _objects[indexPath.row];
    self.detailViewController.detailItem = [object objectForKey:@"detail"];
    self.detailViewController.titleItem = [object objectForKey:@"title"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.detailViewController animated:YES];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method is always picking from your `_objects` array, which you never change when a search is performed. When `shouldReloadTableForSearchString` is called you only populate `searchData`, which is never fed back into `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and `numberOfRowsInSection` to show the filtered results.

One way to handle that is to do something like this (untested) in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }

    NSArray* sourceArray = tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView ? searchData : _objects;

    cell.textLabel.text = [[sourceArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"title"];

    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[sourceArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"detail"];

    return cell;
}
```

and also in your `numberOfRowsInSection`

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView){
        return searchData.count;
    }else
    {
       return _objects.count;
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi foggzilla, thank you for your answer.. i am a bit new to this, so when you write "use searchData and _objects array to populate your cell" is it then something like this you meen:        
        cell = [self.searchData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    else
    {
        cell = [self._objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];  
?...

Comment: I updated the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method in my answer to clarify, but yes that is what i'm getting at.

Comment: Sorry foggzilla, but i think you lost me there... do i make a NSArray of _object? so the code look like this:    
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
    {
        //use searchData to populate your cell
        NSArray *_objects = [self.searchData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    else
    {
        //use _objects array to populate cell
         NSArray *_objects = [self._objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }  
?

Comment: When `cellForRowAtIndexPath` gets called you don't have to make anything, just decide which nsarray to use to populate the cell contents. This is done for you by this line: `NSArray* sourceArray = tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView ? searchData : _objects;`. If you run this code is it not working?

Comment: No, then this come up:#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "AppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
} Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

Comment: when i run it, simulator starts an open the app. detailview works, but no mater what i wrote in search bar it gives "no result".. and when i fx. type "T" and "D" it crash and gives the message "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT"

Comment: you'll need to debug and step through those methods to see if searchData is being populated, what the crash is exactly, etc. The core of your issue is that you weren't telling cellForRowAtIndexPath to use your searchData but there may be other issues going on that should become clear if you step through the code. let me know if you continue to be stuck

Comment: Ok, i try :-)..

But i do not now where to begin...

I give it a try to see if i can figure out how the debug works, and  take an ekstra look at the code..

Thanks

Comment: for debugging tips check out this apple documentation [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/060-Debug_Your_App/debug_app.html).

Comment: Hi figgzilla, i have try to change the code a little bid.. but i still god the same crash when i try to search, and i think it is the "- (void)filterContentForSearchText" that is the problem. I have try to debug and i think i now where the problem is, but i dont now how to fix it.(I have taken the searcbar sample code from apples developer library)... I sent the project to apple support last week, but they seems to answer me very strange and very late, and now they are closed all the next week... Are there any change to sent the project to you so you can see it and help me?

Comment: can you see my profile details? you can email on that email if you like. Send me the stack trace and your source files and I'll take a look when I can.

Comment: No i cant see your details.. But you can sent a email to marc.stuhr.christensen@gmail.com then i can sent you the project..... Thank you..